# How to Add image/logo for Bot in MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have created a Bot and uploaded it to MS teams. I have already added the icons in the manifest.The uploaded icons appear only at the heading but not in the conversation.

[image]

Comment: Did you add the icon to the bot while creating it? Could you please try sign out and sign in and see if the image appears? Bot image and name are cached and usually takes some time to load the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard this is apparently a "bug" that the relevant Microsoft team is dealing with, but, basically, you need to ALSO set the icon in the Azure portal, in your bot registration. Go to the Settings screen, and there's an option to upload an icon - you can use the same one you used in your Teams manifest of course.

Don't forget to click the "Save" button at the top of the settings screen when you're done. See example screenshot:
[image]

I forgot to add, very importantly, that this can take up to 24 hours for the change to come through, I think