# Can we build a product which enables end user to create conversational chat bot using bot framework on a self hosted environment?

Tags: botframework

I want to develop a product which simplifies the way of creating conversational chat bots using Microsoft BotFramework SDK. As we can build and host web application on-premise completely.

So can we build the similar thing using bot framework on a self hosted environment?

Here is the link for Microsoft Bot Framework: https://dev.botframework.com/

Comment: To confirm, you mean you want -everything- to be able to run on premises?

Comment: Also, what do you mean about wanting users to be able to "create" the bots?

Comment: yes, because some of users might use it for their intranet only.

Comment: If you are using the bot framework services, then the Bot does need to be internet-accessible, but it's certainly possible to -host- the bot anywhere you like, on premises or elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks Hilton, Here end users means organisations. its like a B2B solution, so an organisation can build a conversational workflow for their end customers.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow It would  be ok to enable the internet access but we do not want to use any service of azure which will have reoccurring cost.

Comment: Did you make any more progress with this?

Comment: @KrishnaBhanuSingh Did you find my answer to be complete? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, indeed, build a bot entirely on-premises/self-hosted, provided that you don't need to connect to a Channel like Teams.

#### Background

Basically, bots communicate via:

```
User interaction with DirectLine Client (like Web Chat) ->
    DirectLine API receives data and sends to bot ->
        Bot hosted anywhere receives message
```

Note:

WebChat is just a DirectLine client. *If* you want to build your own WebChat, you can [clone the repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) and build it yourself. However, that all this does is make it so you can host your own `webchat.js` file, if you *really* want to be self-hosted.

#### Steps

With that in mind, all you need is:

1. A Direct Line client like [Web Chat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) (specify `domain` property with your own endpoint when you call `createDirectLine`), or you can [write your own client](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS)
2. You own DirectLine API implementation like [`offline-directline`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-directline) ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55812986/how-can-i-use-offline-directline-for-microsofts-botframework-v4))
3. Host your bot somewhere

#### Security

With this approach, you won't be able to use the typical appId/password setup.

You can manually implement our security protocol by following [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Even though it is possible to manually implement the security protocol, we recommend reusing [our existing open-source libraries](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/tree/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Connector)

Comment: thanks @mdrichardson for sharing useful information on bot

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers, putting a more complete answer here. Since the option exists to have internet connectivity, I'd definitely suggest creating the solution as a "regular" Bot Framework bot, using the Azure Bot registration. Importantly, there are TWO options to do this - the most obvious one creates a "registration" for the bot but ALSO defaults to hosting it in an Azure Web App, which has a cost associated that can be quite significant. HOWEVER, there's another option, to create just a "Bot Channel" registration, which means you get a bot **registered** in Azure, but not necessarily **hosted** in Azure.

I've described this more in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59368817/chatbot-retrieve-data-from-sharepoint-on-premise-issue/59646599#59646599) and you want to use the "Bot Channels Registration" in Azure, not the "Web App Bot". Then, on the "settings" screen you can define what the bot's **actual** address is (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59627264/how-to-add-image-logo-for-bot-in-ms-teams/59627486#59627486) for a view of the Settings screen).

So, overall that should help - basically the bot just needs to have an HTTPS, internet-accessible endpoint. HOWEVER, that said, it's possible to host your bots inside Azure Functions, rather than Azure Web Apps, and the cost is **dramatically** cheaper (cents vs dollars, especially with low traffic). It's a bit of work, especially as the default samples default to the more standard options, but it works quite well.

I've recently launched a new blog, by the way, and I've got a post describing some of  what I've learned so far about how bots work, that would be good to know as part of this. See [How Bot Calls Actually Work](https://hilton.giesenow.com/how-bot-calls-actually-work).

Comment: I won't downvote because your answer has some additional context that can be useful. However, *please* don't post something as fact about the Bot Framework unless you know for certain it is. A bot *can* be entirely self-hosted.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT, I might well be wrong (wouldn't even be the first time for today!), so thanks for reviewing and for your very detailed answer, I learned some important things (hence the upvote). In this case though, following a few q+a's in the comments of the original question, it seemed like "self hosting" wasn't actually the biggest challenge, rather it was dealing with the costs of hosting in Azure, and more specifically the azure web app model, which as you know is not required at all, even though it's kind of the "default" for "create" in Azure. [space lmiitation, continuing below]

Comment: As a result, *in this case*,  I think self-hosting per se would incur a lot of additional overhead, but actually add additional limitations that might not be actually wanted. For instance, it means implementing a security protocol, as per your link, but also means the bot *can't* be added to, e.g., Teams later, and this all because, mostly, it's about cost avoidance on Azure. Unless you think I'm totally misinterpreting things?

Comment: I absolutely agree that your answer provides good additional considerations/options. My only real issue was that your answer appears to suggest that it can't be done. IMO, OP is still looking for something that doesn't use Azure at all, which is possible.

Comment: So as it stands right now, OP has (hopefully good) answers for both approaches :-). Fyi, I updated the blog post that I referenced, to include some of this that you posted. Will email you separately about that (hoping that's ok)

Answer (score 0):

We're in the process of migrating from an entirely on-premise solution with our own DirectLine server to Azure Bot Channels Registration because of the requirement for MS Teams integration.